how to retrieve a file using php
I want to retrieve a file/image from specific path in php, I was tried different ways like file_get_contents and opendir and readdir like etc , but unable to find any solutions, Can you please help on this issue.
Below are the static and dynamic file paths adding.

         $static_file_path = 'http://100.100.10.101/dev/livedev/srm/trunk/FILE_UPLOADS/2024/06/27/EBS_sep3.csv';
    $dynamic_file_path = base_url()."FILE_UPLOADS/2024/06/27/EBS_sep3.csv";

I was tried below methods all are showing file not exist .
public function getfilename2(){
    //$file_path = 'http://100.100.10.101/dev/livedev/srm/trunk/FILE_UPLOADS/2024/06/27/EBS_sep3.csv';
    $file_path = base_url()."FILE_UPLOADS/2024/06/27/EBS_sep3.csv";

    // Open a file for reading
    $handle = fopen($file_path, "r");

    // Read data from the file
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        echo $line;
    }

    // Close the file handle
    fclose($handle);

}

way2 below
public function getfilename(){ 

//$file_path = 'http://100.100.10.101/dev/livedev/srm/trunk/FILE_UPLOADS/2024/06/27/EBS_sep3.csv'; 

$file_path = base_url()."FILE_UPLOADS/2024/06/27/EBS_sep3.csv";

if (file_exists($file_path)) {
    // Set headers for CSV file download
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($file_path) . '"');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file_path));
    header('Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');

    // Clear output buffer
    ob_clean();
    flush();

    // Read the file and output it to the browser
    readfile($file_path);
    exit;
} else {
    // File not found
    echo "File not found at path: " . $file_path;
}

}

what does base_url function return

The primary issue in your code is that the file_exists function and the readfile function are intended to work with the filesystem path, not a URL. When you use base_url() to generate the file path, it creates a URL, but file_exists and readfile need a local filesystem path.

@desboisrob readfile can be used with HTTP URLs, if allow_url_fopen is set to true. file_exists however won't work with HTTP URLs, because as https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php shows, the wrapper does not support stat functionality.

A guess: File path is more likely: __DIR__.'/relative_path/to/file.csv'. __DIR__ is the home directory of your php script.

Any one of you Could you please suggest how to retrieve file from specific path in codeigniter Please

I want to retrieve file/image from path in php codeigniter Please

You can use CodeIgniter's FCPATH constant to get the path to the directory CodeIgniter's index.php file is in.
Assuming your FILE_UPLOADS folder is in that same directory, try $file_path = FCPATH."FILE_UPLOADS/2024/06/27/EBS_sep3.csv";

https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/general/common_functions.html#core-constants

With file_get_contents....?
<?
$content = @file_get_contents("http://.../example.csv");

if($content)
{
    echo "<pre>";
    echo $content;
    echo "</pre>";
}
else echo "No File";
?>


Why include the error suppression operator?

@David To avoid the warning message

@Juan .. If I want to retrieve image also is this script work ??

@NiranajanC You have the contents of the remote file with this simple script. Afterwards it is possible to save this content
